# How can I list packages not included in any R task view?

Tags: r, cran

I've been looking through the [R Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) a lot lately and have found that some packages of interest are not included in any task views.  Is there an established way to find the complement of the packages listed in the task views?

I realize that via `XML` and processing of the `ctv` files (e.g http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Econometrics.ctv), I can find the union of all of the packages listed in the `<packagelist>` node, and that `available.packages()` can list all of the available packages for download.  Is that the trick, or am I missing some trick in using a site like [CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/) or [CRANtastic](http://crantastic.org/)?

Update 1 (don't do this - see my answer below): I overlooked mentioning that CRAN lists "In views:" for packages.  So, it seems that behind the scenes some information is kept matching packages to the views that they're in.  One could easily (and rudely) scrape all of the CRAN package pages and grep for "In views:".  That was my initial idea until I came across `ctv`, which is a bit more elegant.

Update 2: I overlooked linking to [ctv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ctv/index.html).  The package documentation is interesting if you're into Task Views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No hidden tricks, just re-create something like CRANberries (which starts by calling `available.packages()` and comparing to the state data it stored in a local database).

In your case you may want to compute set differences between what `available.packages()` gets you and what you get from the `ctv` package concerning the Task View selections.

*Edit 1* Your 'Update 1' idea is crude. Too crude.  The meta-information at CRAN comes from, methinks, properly accounting for meta-information: first set is all packages, the add sets for each Task View, possibly split between 'listed' and 'recommended' and aggregate up.

*Edit 2* I think you just use code from `ctv` to parse its files, out come sets. We used that in `cran2deb` to defines smaller test sets for package creation.  Given that set (and the other data), they can generate the web pages. I think you may be over-complicating things.  R makes that possible as I also know too darn well ;-)

Comment: +1 And you would know. :-)  Do you know how the "In views" is set?  I imagine there's a bit of magic behind the scenes at CRAN HQ, if only I can unlock the magic SQL query.

Comment: You were faster in writing your edit than I was in submitting my comment.  :)

Answer (score 6):

I should have read the `ctv` documentation more carefully.  The answer was right there: there's a .rds file called `Views.rds`. Here's a step-by-step method:

```
myRepos         <- "http://cran.r-project.org"
tmpfile         <- tempfile()
download.file(paste(myRepos, "src/contrib/Views.rds", sep = "/"), destfile = tmpfile)

myViews         <- .readRDS(tmpfile)
func_listPkgs   <- function(x){return(x$packagelist$name)}
aggRaw          <- lapply(myViews, func_listPkgs)
aggInViews      <- unique(unlist(aggRaw))

availRaw        <- available.packages(contriburl = paste(myRepos, "src/contrib", sep = "/"))
availPkgs       <- rownames(availRaw)
notInViews      <- setdiff(availPkgs, aggInViews)
```

Here's what this is doing:

1. It gets the `Views.rds` file from a CRAN mirror.
2. It loads the Views.rds into a data frame.  Note: Prior to 2.13, one needed to use `.readRDS`, which is now `readRDS` with 2.13.  `.readRDS` still works, though it's deprecated.
3. It gets the list of available packages.  This could be made more direct: there is a file called `Packages.gz` that could be downloaded, but then we have to parse it.  Let's stick with tools already available.  :)
4. It runs a diff on the two lists.  For fun, try the opposite diff: `oddPackages <- setdiff(aggInViews, availPkgs)`.  Some of these are packages in base R.  Others are ??? who knows.

Comment: You get a firm 'yup' from me for that :)

Comment: For bonus credit: someone could take this set and build a multi-class classifier suggesting potential task views for different packages, based on dependencies, suggestions, authors, and keyword matching (for the NLP crowd :)).